# How does Path mapping work in ReSharper?

Tags: sharepoint, resharper

I have been struggling to find a good detailed explanation for that anywhere. So I have a project (destined to be deployed to SharePoint) which is organized as follows:

```
MyProject
    12
        TEMPLATE
            CONTROLTEMPLATES
            FEATURES
            LAYOUTS
                Images
                    MyImage.png
```

In a css file somewhere I have the following line:

```
.myClass { background: url(/_Layouts/Images/MyImage.png); }
```

Obviously the whole url comes out red and I have a ReSharper error stating:

```
Path C:\MySolutionFolder\MyProject\_Layouts\Images\MyImage.png not found
```

So at no point I expect ReSharper to understand anything about SharePoint, I just want to understand how to map folders.

So I went to the project's properties, and created a new mapping:

*Substitute* **/_layouts** with **C:\MySolutionFolder\MyProject\12\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS**

That does not seem to do anything, so I tried playing around, and the only thing I found to do *something* is:

*Substitute* **_Layouts** with **C:\MySolutionFolder\MyProject\12\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS**

Instead of the previous error, I now only have the *_Layouts* part of the url in red, and a new ReSharper error:

```
Symbol '_Layouts' doesn't exist in CSS 3.0
```

That does not make much more sense to me, but it is the only thing I found to have any effect.
Note that it seems wrong to put this path mapping without the initial slash, because it feels like it would replace the word '_layouts' in any position in the path, when it should only be replaced at the root path of the site.

And also, the fact that the mapping changes the error seems to be case sensitive, something I do not understand for a url path mapping (urls are not case sensitive are they?).

Also, using Ignore instead of Substitute does not make the error disappear. It seems the only way there is is to disable the error, which IMO is really a bad thing.

Behaviour has been reproduced on 6.1 and 7.0.

The project is made for SP 2007 as the 12 suggests, the problem is on VS 2010 (I have not tried any other version).

And if the path mapping is not what I think it is, is there any way around this? A plugin, for instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot for your feedback.
It looks like the functionality is broken and will be fixed in the bugfix update ASAP. I've created a youTrack issue for the problem http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-328783

Comment: Thank you very much. I am not sure it's a SharePoint-related issue though. I suppose it would do the same thing if I was trying to set up a mapping for any kind of website (with a virtual path for instance).

Comment: Fixed in R#er 7.1 EAP. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be broken again. Substitution is supposed to replace the matched part, right? In my case it is just prefixing the path with the specified replacement text ...

Comment: I have no way to test this now as I am not working on that project anymore